# How to resize dynamically a Part of an e(fx)clipse (or eclipse RCP) application

Tags: javafx, eclipse-rcp, e4

I'm trying to set dynamically a Part size in the code with e(fx)clipse. But it didn't work. I don't know what attribut I have to set.

I tried something like this :

```
 @Inject
 EModelService modelService;

 @Inject
 MApplication application;

  @PostConstruct
  void init(BorderPane pane) {
      MPart myPart = (MPart) modelService.find("mypartid", application);
      myPart .setContainerData("80"); //80 or 5000 or 1, nothing works
   }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug in the renderer - https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=435678 - i would also suggest that you use our forum for questions. You would get an answer most of the time a lot faster!